# Как понять эту запись в Kotlin? Что есть что?

Tags: kotlin

Я изучаю `Java`, никогда с `Kotlin`'ом дело не имел, хотя планирую в скором будущем. 
Сейчас пытаюсь разобрать один паттерн, пример использования `Android Architecture Components`, который написан на `Koltin`'e и столкнулся с синтаксисом (кажется класса), который не могу понять.

Объясните, плиз, что здесь, чем является, (типа `MyDatabaseLiveData` это класс, который ... (что этот тип делает после двоеточия), а `LiveData<List<Article>>()` это ...
С переопределяемым методом здесь все понятно.
Спасибо огромное!

```
class MyDatabaseLiveData : LiveData<List<SomeClass>>() {
   override fun onActive() {
      super.onActive()
      ...    
    }
}
```

Смею предположить, что этот синтаксис типа extends в java.
Так?

```
class MyDatabaseLiveData extends LiveData<List<SomeClass>>() {
       @Override
       public void fun onActive() {
          super.onActive();
          ...    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, ваш перевод верен.

`class MyDatabaseLiveData` - `public class MyDatabaseLiveData`

символ `:` - заменяет `extends` в `java`

`LiveData` - класс родитель

В Android studio вы можете преобрзовать Kotlin в Java

```
Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Decompile Kotlin to Java
```

Comment: Преобразовать то можно, но только, если сам код компилируется без ошибок, в противном случае эта опция недоступна. Т.е. получается надо чуть ли не весь проект со всеми dependencies откомпилировать. Проще спросить здесь. За что Вам и спасибо!